# Apache Rewriterule Same text in different cases need to be redirect to a common url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how to write a rewrite rule to merge with case sensitive, that the source is the text with different case and point to the common destination

for example

```
RewriteRule ^/nextgen$ /business-credit.html  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/NEXTGEN$ /business-credit.html  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/NextGen$ /business-credit.html  [R=301,L]
```

Instead of this three rule, is there any possibility to merge in a single rule? please help me to find out this

Comment: what if using `[NC]` ? e.g. `RewriteRule ^/NextGen$ /business-credit.html  [NC] [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

Your Rule needs a NC flag to match the case insensitive URI.

Try :

```
RewriteRule ^/?NextGen$ /business-credit.html  [R=301,L,NC]
```

NC stands for No Case, The flag is important when Request uri string contains Uppercase or lowercas letters.

**Clear your browser's cache before testing this solution.**